# Draw circle canvas and print canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I wanted to draw the circular canvas and wanted to download the canvas with same format. Following is css which i am using

```
canvas {
    width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
}
```

At present i have just apply the css to canvas to look a like it will not print same in fabric js.

Is there any possible way? Because i am trying to create circular canvas and add text and wanted to print same canvas with text and styling.

**Edit:**

Is it possible to draw the circle with same styling in fabric.js

Comment: I don't understand, what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to download the canvas with circular form. You can check the following url http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7F7Vn/

Comment: `border-radius: 50%` on canvas element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really have a circular canvas in fabricjs, but you  can clip a canvas to look like a circle.

i did a circle that has radius half of the canvas, and is positioned in the center.
Effect is same as your example.

Look the fiddle:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,200,200,0,2*Math.PI);
}
canvas.backgroundColor = 'blue';
var rect =  new fabric.Rect({width: 100, height:100, fill:'red', top:30, left:30});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="http://www.fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
```